# Lua cannot find module in C++ api?

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am call lua in C++ applications. I have several lua files to call, like `RunAPI_1208.lua` , `JSON.lua`, etc. All the lua file is called by main.lua. While in C++ , I run all the file and finally run `main.lua`. I met this problem. I am using Cocos2d-x 2.2.6. How can I solve it?

```
[string "Main.lua"]:9: module 'RunAPI_1208' not found:
    no field package.preload['RunAPI_1208']
    no file './RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208/init.lua'
    no file './RunAPI_1208.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
Cocos2d: [string "Main.lua"]:9: module 'RunAPI_1208' not found:
    no field package.preload['RunAPI_1208']
    no file './RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208/init.lua'
    no file './RunAPI_1208.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/RunAPI_1208.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
```

And this is my main.lua:

```
local run = require("RunAPI_1208")
```

Comment: By fixing the [module search path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path)! What's the current directory of your running program and where lies your `RunAPI_1208.lua`?

Comment: @Youka I am calling lua from C++, lua files is under Resource folder. I call luaL_loadbuffer load `RunAPI_1208.lua` before I call `main.lua`.

Comment: In your question you wrote to `require` them in your `main.lua`. Now you say you run them from memory/buffer in C++. What now?

Comment: There's [luaL_dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dofile) for direct file execution and [luaL_dostring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_dostring) in case you really need them in memory first. When you use [require](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require) in Lua, you can simply extend the search paths by appending something like `;Resource/?.lua` to [package.path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) (depends on your current process directory).

Comment: @Youka Sorry for my mistake. All the lua is called from C++, but I load RunAPI_1208.lua before main.lua. Finally I call main.lua and at that time, main.lua cannot found module `RunAPI_1208`.